# ADFS connection in Xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin, adfs, adal

I have been through various blogs and posts but I was not able to find ADFS token based authentication. Where can I get this problem solved???
I have tried for Azure ADAL but thats not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the latest ADAL preview (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/3.0.110281957-alpha) and the latest ADFS you should be able to obtain ADFS tokens from your Xamarin applications. The sample https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-MultiTarget-DotNet should be adaptable to go against ADFS. For ADFS specific settings see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633593.aspx - it's a it old, the ADFS side instructions should apply here as well.
 The current ADAL preview has limitations (for example, it will only work with IOS classic API) but those will be solved as we refresh the preview.